# View performance vs WITH performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, view

I have a query that select from view and from more several tables.

When I'm execute this query "as is" - the performance is very bad.

When I'm taking the view's query and add it to the outer query with `WITH CLAUSE`, it runs very fast.

My test shows that the problem is not in the view's query itself, but with the way that the optimizer joins the view data with the other data.

What is the explanation to this issue?

There are some missing fields in the select queries because of 30K characters limit..

```
--View:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DWH.CC_MC_VIEW AS
SELECT /*+ full(E) */
DISTINCT/* a lot of fields */
FROM dwh.t2002_merkazei_tamhir_cur a
LEFT JOIN dwh.allovdim b
ON a.oved_achrai_char = TO_CHAR(b.mis_oved)
AND a.company         = b.company
LEFT JOIN dwh.t2003_kodei_merkazei_tamhir h
ON h.year     = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-28,'yyyy')
AND h.erech   = a.c01_agaf
AND h.company = A.company
AND h.amuda   = '01'
LEFT JOIN dwh.t2003_kodei_merkazei_tamhir g
ON g.erech    = a.c03_minhal_rb
AND g.amuda   = '03'
AND g.year    = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-28,'yyyy')
AND g.company = A.company
LEFT JOIN DWH_COMPANIES E
ON A.COMPANY = E.COM_COMPANY_CODE
LEFT JOIN dwh.t2003_kodei_merkazei_tamhir d
ON d.erech    = a.c02_minhalhativa
AND d.amuda   = '02'
AND D.year    = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-28,'yyyy')
AND A.COMPANY = D.COMPANY
LEFT JOIN dwh.allovdim c
ON d.oved_achrai = c.mis_oved
AND d.company    = c.company
LEFT JOIN DWH_COMPANIES F
ON D.COMPANY    = F.COM_COMPANY_CODE
WHERE KOD_SGIRA = 1;
```

query on view (bad performance)

```
(SELECT  ROUND(dwh.plm_docdelivery.RELEASEDDATE-dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROCESSSTARTDATE),
ROUND(sysdate         -dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROCESSSTARTDATE),
dwh.plm_docdelivery.*,
dwh.cc_mc_view.*,
dwh.plm_programs.*,
FROM    dwh.plm_docdelivery,
DWH.PLM_PROGRAMS,
dwh.cc_mc_view,
dwh.allovdim ENG_OWNER,
dwh.plm_last_rev
WHERE
(
dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER=dwh.plm_programs.PROGRAMNUMBER
AND dwh.plm_docdelivery.COMPANY=dwh.plm_programs.COMPANY
AND dwh.plm_docdelivery.LOGISTICCOMPANY=dwh.plm_programs.LOGISTICCOMPANY
)
AND
(
dwh.plm_docdelivery.ENGOWNERID= ENG_OWNER.EMP_ID(+)
)
AND
(
dwh.cc_mc_view.MERKAZ_TAMHIR(+)=ENG_OWNER.MIS_TAMH
AND dwh.cc_mc_view.COMPANY(+)  =ENG_OWNER.COMPANY
)
AND
(
dwh.plm_last_rev.COMPANY=dwh.plm_docdelivery.COMPANY
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.LOGISTICCOMPANY=dwh.plm_docdelivery.LOGISTICCOMPANY
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.PROGRAMNUMBER=dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.DOCUMENT=dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENT
)
AND
(ENG_OWNER.COMPANY<>'SOL')
AND
(dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER IN ('X395','X419','X422','X379','X454','X372','X308', 'X394','X426','X433','X423','X391','X391A','X393','X490','X510','X460','X466A','X466B', 'X466C','X448','T622','T610','X461','X470','X520','X436','X560','D308','X922B','X922','X435', 'X494','X402','X995SP','X493','X481','X990','T799')
AND
(dwh.plm_docdelivery.CDRLTYPE    <> 'SDRL'
OR dwh.plm_docdelivery.CDRLTYPE IS NULL)
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.LAST_REV = dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENTREVISION
AND((dwh.plm_docdelivery.AUTHORDATE <= '16-07-2017 00:00:00'
AND(dwh.plm_docdelivery.STATUS    IN ( '(Freeze)','(Released)' )
OR dwh.plm_docdelivery.STATUS IS NULL))
OR dwh.plm_docdelivery.RELEASEDDATE IS NOT NULL)
AND dwh.plm_programs.COMPANY IN ('ESL','TCL'))
MINUS
SELECT  ROUND(dwh.plm_docdelivery.RELEASEDDATE-dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROCESSSTARTDATE),
ROUND(sysdate         -dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROCESSSTARTDATE),
dwh.plm_docdelivery.STATUS,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.SIGNERSLEFT,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.RELEASEDDATE,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER,
dwh.plm_programs.PROGRAMNAME,
dwh.cc_mc_view.MINHALHATIVA,
TO_CHAR(dwh.plm_docdelivery.PLANNEDVALUE)
||
dwh.plm_docdelivery.TIMEUNIT
||
' '
||
CASE
WHEN dwh.plm_docdelivery.PLANNEDRELATION='After'
THEN '+'
WHEN dwh.plm_docdelivery.PLANNEDRELATION='Before'
THEN '-'
ELSE ''
END
||
dwh.plm_docdelivery.CDRLGATENAME,
ENG_OWNER.MISHPAHA,
ENG_OWNER.MISHPAHA_ENG,
ENG_OWNER.PRATI,
ENG_OWNER.PRATI_ENG,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.ENGOWNERID,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.ENGDISCIPLINE,
dwh.cc_mc_view.ACHRAI_HATIVA_NAME,
dwh.cc_mc_view.OVED_ACHRAI_HATIVA_FULL,
dwh.cc_mc_view.ACHRAI_MT_NAME,
dwh.cc_mc_view.OVED_ACHRAI_MT_FULL,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENTREVISION,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENTNAME,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENT,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.DELIVERY,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.CURRENTUSER ,
dwh.cc_mc_view.MERKAZ_TAMHIR,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.CDRLTYPE,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.CDRL,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.AUTHORDATE,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOC_REV_CREATION_DATE,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.DELIVERY_CREATION_DATE,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.GATEORIGINALDATE,
dwh.plm_programs.STATUS_DATE,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.ProcedureName,
dwh.plm_last_rev.LAST_REV,
dwh.plm_programs.COMPANY
FROM    dwh.plm_docdelivery,
DWH.PLM_PROGRAMS,
dwh.cc_mc_view,
dwh.allovdim ENG_OWNER,
dwh.plm_last_rev
WHERE
(dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER      =dwh.plm_programs.PROGRAMNUMBER
AND dwh.plm_docdelivery.COMPANY        =dwh.plm_programs.COMPANY
AND dwh.plm_docdelivery.LOGISTICCOMPANY=dwh.plm_programs.LOGISTICCOMPANY)
AND
(dwh.plm_docdelivery.ENGOWNERID= ENG_OWNER.EMP_ID(+))
AND
(dwh.cc_mc_view.MERKAZ_TAMHIR(+)=ENG_OWNER.MIS_TAMH
AND dwh.cc_mc_view.COMPANY(+)  =ENG_OWNER.COMPANY)
AND
(dwh.plm_last_rev.COMPANY            =dwh.plm_docdelivery.COMPANY
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.LOGISTICCOMPANY=dwh.plm_docdelivery.LOGISTICCOMPANY
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.PROGRAMNUMBER  =dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.DOCUMENT       =dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENT)
AND
(ENG_OWNER.COMPANY<>'SOL')
AND
(dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER IN ('X395','X419','X422','X379','X454','X372','X308', 'X394','X426','X433','X423','X391','X391A','X393','X490','X510','X460','X466A','X466B', 'X466C','X448','T622','T610','X461','X470','X520','X436','X560','D308','X922B','X922','X435', 'X494','X402','X995SP','X493','X481','X990','T799')
AND dwh.plm_docdelivery.DELIVERY  IS NOT NULL
AND dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENT  IS NULL
AND dwh.plm_programs.COMPANY      IN ('CMP1','CMP2')))
```

Explain plan for the view (bad performance)

```
Plan hash value: 822592127

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Id  | Operation| Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |              |    57 | 52896 | 32848   (2)| 00:01:39 |
|   1 |  MINUS   |              |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SORT UNIQUE            |              |    57 | 26448 | 16424   (2)| 00:00:50 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER    |              |    57 | 26448 | 16423   (2)| 00:00:50 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS         |              |    20 |  5540 | 14146   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN           |              |    20 |  4660 | 14106   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL  | PLM_LAST_REV |    50 |  1300 | 13959   (3)| 00:00:42 |
|   7 |       NESTED LOOPS       |              |   798 |   161K|   147   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |        NESTED LOOPS      |              |   798 |   161K|   147   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL| PLM_PROGRAMS |    44 |  1496 |    14   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN | IDX_DELIVERY_1               |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | PLM_DOCDELIVERY              |    18 |  3114 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | ALLOVDIM     |     1 |    44 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN   | ALLOVDIM_I_EMP_CMP           |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |     VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE| CC_MC_VIEW   |     1 |   187 |   114   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |      SORT UNIQUE         |              |     1 |   217 |   114   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |       FILTER             |              |       |       |            |          |
|  17 |        NESTED LOOPS OUTER|              |     1 |   217 |   113   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |         NESTED LOOPS OUTER               |              |     1 |   173 |    97   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |          HASH JOIN OUTER |              |     1 |   167 |    96   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |           NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |              |     1 |   161 |    48   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |            NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |              |     1 |   117 |    46   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  22 |             NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |              |     1 |    90 |    32   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  23 |              NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |              |     1 |    65 |    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T2002_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR_CUR    |     1 |    40 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 25 |INDEX RANGE SCAN          | T2002_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR_CUR_I1 |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  26 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T2003_KODEI_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR  |     1 |    25 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 27 |INDEX RANGE SCAN          | T2003_K_MT97_Y_AE_I          |     1 |       |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  28 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | T2003_KODEI_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR  |     1 |    25 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 29 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN           | T2003_K_MT97_Y_AE_I          |     1 |       |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  30 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | T2003_KODEI_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR  |     1 |    27 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 31 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN            | T2003_K_MT97_Y_AE_I          |     1 |       |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  32 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | ALLOVDIM     |     1 |    44 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 33 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN             | ALLOVDIM_I_CMP_MIS           |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 34 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL              | DWH_COMPANIES|     1 |     6 |    47   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  35 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | DWH_COMPANIES|     1 |     6 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 36 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | COMP_IDX1    |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  37 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | ALLOVDIM     |     1 |    44 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 38 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN| ALLOVDIM_I_CMP_MIS           |     1 |       |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  39 |   SORT UNIQUE            |              |    57 | 26448 | 16424   (2)| 00:00:50 |
|  40 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER    |              |    57 | 26448 | 16423   (2)| 00:00:50 |
|  41 |     NESTED LOOPS         |              |    20 |  5540 | 14145   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|* 42 |      HASH JOIN           |              |    20 |  4660 | 14105   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|* 43 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL  | PLM_LAST_REV |    50 |  1300 | 13959   (3)| 00:00:42 |
|  44 |       NESTED LOOPS       |              |    64 | 13248 |   146   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  45 |        NESTED LOOPS      |              |    64 | 13248 |   146   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 46 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL| PLM_PROGRAMS |    44 |  1496 |    14   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|* 47 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN | IDX_DELIVERY_1               |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 48 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | PLM_DOCDELIVERY              |     1 |   173 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  49 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | ALLOVDIM     |     1 |    44 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 50 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN   | ALLOVDIM_I_EMP_CMP           |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  51 |     VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE| CC_MC_VIEW   |     1 |   187 |   114   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|  52 |      SORT UNIQUE         |              |     1 |   217 |   114   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|* 53 |       FILTER             |              |       |       |            |          |
|  54 |        NESTED LOOPS OUTER|              |     1 |   217 |   113   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  55 |         NESTED LOOPS OUTER               |              |     1 |   173 |    97   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|* 56 |          HASH JOIN OUTER |              |     1 |   167 |    96   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|  57 |           NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |              |     1 |   161 |    48   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  58 |            NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |              |     1 |   117 |    46   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  59 |             NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |              |     1 |    90 |    32   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  60 |              NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |              |     1 |    65 |    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 61 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T2002_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR_CUR    |     1 |    40 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 62 |INDEX RANGE SCAN          | T2002_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR_CUR_I1 |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  63 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T2003_KODEI_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR  |     1 |    25 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 64 |INDEX RANGE SCAN          | T2003_K_MT97_Y_AE_I          |     1 |       |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  65 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | T2003_KODEI_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR  |     1 |    25 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 66 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN           | T2003_K_MT97_Y_AE_I          |     1 |       |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  67 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | T2003_KODEI_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR  |     1 |    27 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 68 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN            | T2003_K_MT97_Y_AE_I          |     1 |       |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  69 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | ALLOVDIM     |     1 |    44 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 70 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN             | ALLOVDIM_I_CMP_MIS           |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 71 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL              | DWH_COMPANIES|     1 |     6 |    47   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  72 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | DWH_COMPANIES|     1 |     6 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 73 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | COMP_IDX1    |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  74 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | ALLOVDIM     |     1 |    44 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 75 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN| ALLOVDIM_I_CMP_MIS           |     1 |       |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

Variant with WITH clause ( good performance )

```
with CC as
(SELECT /*+full(E) */  
DISTINCT/* a lot of fields */
FROM dwh.t2002_merkazei_tamhir_cur a
LEFT JOIN dwh.allovdim b
ON a.oved_achrai_char = TO_CHAR(b.mis_oved)
AND a.company         = b.company
LEFT JOIN dwh.t2003_kodei_merkazei_tamhir h
ON h.year     = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-28,'yyyy')
AND h.erech   = a.c01_agaf
AND h.company = A.company
AND h.amuda   = '01'
LEFT JOIN dwh.t2003_kodei_merkazei_tamhir g
ON g.erech    = a.c03_minhal_rb
AND g.amuda   = '03'
AND g.year    = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-28,'yyyy')
AND g.company = A.company
LEFT JOIN DWH_COMPANIES E
ON A.COMPANY = E.COM_COMPANY_CODE
LEFT JOIN dwh.t2003_kodei_merkazei_tamhir d
ON d.erech    = a.c02_minhalhativa
AND d.amuda   = '02'
AND D.year    = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-28,'yyyy')
AND A.COMPANY = D.COMPANY
LEFT JOIN dwh.allovdim c
ON d.oved_achrai = c.mis_oved
AND d.company    = c.company
LEFT JOIN DWH_COMPANIES F
on D.COMPANY    = F.COM_COMPANY_CODE
WHERE KOD_SGIRA = 1
)
(
SELECT  ROUND(dwh.plm_docdelivery.RELEASEDDATE-dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROCESSSTARTDATE),
ROUND(sysdate         -dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROCESSSTARTDATE),
dwh.plm_docdelivery.*,
dwh.cc_mc_view.*,
dwh.plm_programs.*,
FROM dwh.plm_docdelivery,
DWH.PLM_PROGRAMS,
cc,
dwh.allovdim ENG_OWNER,
dwh.plm_last_rev
WHERE
(
dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER=dwh.plm_programs.PROGRAMNUMBER
AND dwh.plm_docdelivery.COMPANY=dwh.plm_programs.COMPANY
AND dwh.plm_docdelivery.LOGISTICCOMPANY=dwh.plm_programs.LOGISTICCOMPANY
)
AND
(dwh.plm_docdelivery.ENGOWNERID= ENG_OWNER.EMP_ID(+))
AND
(cc.MERKAZ_TAMHIR(+)=ENG_OWNER.MIS_TAMH
AND cc.COMPANY(+)  =ENG_OWNER.COMPANY)
AND
(dwh.plm_last_rev.COMPANY            =dwh.plm_docdelivery.COMPANY
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.LOGISTICCOMPANY=dwh.plm_docdelivery.LOGISTICCOMPANY
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.PROGRAMNUMBER  =dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.DOCUMENT       =dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENT)
AND
(ENG_OWNER.COMPANY<>'SOL')
AND
(dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER IN ('X395','X419','X422','X379','X454','X372','X308', 'X394','X426','X433','X423','X391','X391A','X393','X490','X510','X460','X466A','X466B', 'X466C','X448','T622','T610','X461','X470','X520','X436','X560','D308','X922B','X922','X435', 'X494','X402','X995SP','X493','X481','X990','T799')
AND
(dwh.plm_docdelivery.CDRLTYPE    <> 'SDRL'
OR dwh.plm_docdelivery.CDRLTYPE IS NULL)
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.LAST_REV = dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENTREVISION
AND((dwh.plm_docdelivery.AUTHORDATE <= '16-07-2017 00:00:00'
AND(dwh.plm_docdelivery.STATUS    IN ( '(Freeze)','(Released)' )
OR dwh.plm_docdelivery.STATUS IS NULL))
OR dwh.plm_docdelivery.RELEASEDDATE IS NOT NULL)
AND dwh.plm_programs.COMPANY IN ('ESL','TCL'))
MINUS
SELECT ROUND(dwh.plm_docdelivery.RELEASEDDATE-dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROCESSSTARTDATE),
ROUND(sysdate-dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROCESSSTARTDATE),
dwh.plm_docdelivery.STATUS,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.SIGNERSLEFT,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.RELEASEDDATE,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER,
dwh.plm_programs.PROGRAMNAME,
cc.MINHALHATIVA,
TO_CHAR(dwh.plm_docdelivery.PLANNEDVALUE)
||
dwh.plm_docdelivery.TIMEUNIT
||
' '
||
CASE
WHEN dwh.plm_docdelivery.PLANNEDRELATION='After'
THEN '+'
WHEN dwh.plm_docdelivery.PLANNEDRELATION='Before'
THEN '-'
ELSE ''
END
||
dwh.plm_docdelivery.CDRLGATENAME,
ENG_OWNER.MISHPAHA,
ENG_OWNER.MISHPAHA_ENG,
ENG_OWNER.PRATI,
ENG_OWNER.PRATI_ENG,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.ENGOWNERID,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.ENGDISCIPLINE,
cc.ACHRAI_HATIVA_NAME,
cc.OVED_ACHRAI_HATIVA_FULL,
cc.ACHRAI_MT_NAME,
cc.OVED_ACHRAI_MT_FULL,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENTREVISION,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENTNAME,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENT,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.DELIVERY,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.CURRENTUSER ,
cc.MERKAZ_TAMHIR,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.CDRLTYPE,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.CDRL,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.AUTHORDATE,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOC_REV_CREATION_DATE,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.DELIVERY_CREATION_DATE,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.GATEORIGINALDATE,
dwh.plm_programs.STATUS_DATE,
dwh.plm_docdelivery.ProcedureName,
dwh.plm_last_rev.LAST_REV,
dwh.plm_programs.COMPANY
FROM dwh.plm_docdelivery,DWH.PLM_PROGRAMS,cc,dwh.allovdim ENG_OWNER,dwh.plm_last_rev
WHERE(dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER=dwh.plm_programs.PROGRAMNUMBER
AND dwh.plm_docdelivery.COMPANY=dwh.plm_programs.COMPANY
AND dwh.plm_docdelivery.LOGISTICCOMPANY=dwh.plm_programs.LOGISTICCOMPANY)
AND(dwh.plm_docdelivery.ENGOWNERID=ENG_OWNER.EMP_ID(+))
AND(cc.MERKAZ_TAMHIR(+)=ENG_OWNER.MIS_TAMH
AND cc.COMPANY(+)=ENG_OWNER.COMPANY)
AND(dwh.plm_last_rev.COMPANY=dwh.plm_docdelivery.COMPANY
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.LOGISTICCOMPANY=dwh.plm_docdelivery.LOGISTICCOMPANY
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.PROGRAMNUMBER=dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER
AND dwh.plm_last_rev.DOCUMENT=dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENT)
AND(ENG_OWNER.COMPANY<>'SOL')
AND(dwh.plm_docdelivery.PROGRAMNUMBER IN ('X395','X419','X422','X379','X454','X372','X308', 'X394','X426','X433','X423','X391','X391A','X393','X490','X510','X460','X466A','X466B', 'X466C','X448','T622','T610','X461','X470','X520','X436','X560','D308','X922B','X922','X435', 'X494','X402','X995SP','X493','X481','X990','T799')
AND dwh.plm_docdelivery.DELIVERY IS NOT NULL
AND dwh.plm_docdelivery.DOCUMENT IS NULL
AND dwh.plm_programs.COMPANY IN ('CMP1','CMP2')));
```

Explain plan for WITH clause

```
Plan hash value: 2179438877
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |             |    20 | 18560 |       | 28536   (3)| 00:01:26 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION            |             |       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT      | SYS_TEMP_0FDA4CB1D_E5C2B79E |       |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    HASH UNIQUE        |             |  5692 |  1206K|  1312K|  4670   (2)| 00:00:15 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER             |             |  5692 |  1206K|       |  4245   (2)| 00:00:13 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| DWH_COMPANIES               |   101 |   606 |       |    47   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      HASH JOIN OUTER  |             |  5691 |  1172K|       |  4197   (2)| 00:00:13 |
|*  7 |       HASH JOIN OUTER |             |  5691 |   928K|       |  2452   (2)| 00:00:08 |
|*  8 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER          |             |  5691 |   683K|       |   706   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|   9 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL             | DWH_COMPANIES               |   101 |   606 |       |    47   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |         HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER         |             |  5691 |   650K|       |   659   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  11 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | T2003_KODEI_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR |    25 |   675 |       |    37   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |           INDEX SKIP SCAN             | T2003_K_MT97_Y_AE_I         |    25 |       |       |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |          HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER        |             |  5691 |   500K|       |   621   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  14 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | T2003_KODEI_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR |    25 |   625 |       |    37   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |            INDEX SKIP SCAN            | T2003_K_MT97_Y_AE_I         |    25 |       |       |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |           HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER       |             |  5691 |   361K|       |   584   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  17 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T2003_KODEI_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR |    25 |   625 |       |    37   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |             INDEX SKIP SCAN           | T2003_K_MT97_Y_AE_I         |    25 |       |       |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL          | T2002_MERKAZEI_TAMHIR_CUR   |  5691 |   222K|       |   547   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  20 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL              | ALLOVDIM    | 51269 |  2202K|       |  1744   (2)| 00:00:06 |
|  21 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL               | ALLOVDIM    | 51269 |  2202K|       |  1744   (2)| 00:00:06 |
|  22 |   MINUS               |             |       |       |       |            |          |
|  23 |    SORT UNIQUE        |             |    20 |  9280 |       | 14268   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|* 24 |     HASH JOIN OUTER   |             |    20 |  9280 |       | 14267   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|  25 |      NESTED LOOPS     |             |    20 |  5540 |       | 14146   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|  26 |       NESTED LOOPS    |             |    20 |  5540 |       | 14146   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|* 27 |        HASH JOIN      |             |    20 |  4660 |       | 14106   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|* 28 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL             | PLM_LAST_REV|    50 |  1300 |       | 13959   (3)| 00:00:42 |
|  29 |         NESTED LOOPS  |             |   798 |   161K|       |   147   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|  30 |          NESTED LOOPS |             |   798 |   161K|       |   147   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|* 31 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL           | PLM_PROGRAMS|    44 |  1496 |       |    14   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|* 32 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN            | IDX_DELIVERY_1              |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 33 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | PLM_DOCDELIVERY             |    18 |  3114 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 34 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN               | ALLOVDIM_I_EMP_CMP          |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  35 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | ALLOVDIM    |     1 |    44 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 36 |      VIEW             |             |  5692 |  1039K|       |   121   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  37 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL               | SYS_TEMP_0FDA4CB1D_E5C2B79E |  5692 |  1206K|       |   121   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  38 |    SORT UNIQUE        |             |    20 |  9280 |       | 14268   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|* 39 |     HASH JOIN OUTER   |             |    20 |  9280 |       | 14267   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|  40 |      NESTED LOOPS     |             |    20 |  5540 |       | 14145   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|  41 |       NESTED LOOPS    |             |    20 |  5540 |       | 14145   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|* 42 |        HASH JOIN      |             |    20 |  4660 |       | 14105   (3)| 00:00:43 |
|* 43 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL             | PLM_LAST_REV|    50 |  1300 |       | 13959   (3)| 00:00:42 |
|  44 |         NESTED LOOPS  |             |    64 | 13248 |       |   146   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  45 |          NESTED LOOPS |             |    64 | 13248 |       |   146   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 46 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL           | PLM_PROGRAMS|    44 |  1496 |       |    14   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|* 47 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN            | IDX_DELIVERY_1              |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 48 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | PLM_DOCDELIVERY             |     1 |   173 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 49 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN               | ALLOVDIM_I_EMP_CMP          |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  50 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | ALLOVDIM    |     1 |    44 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 51 |      VIEW             |             |  5692 |  1039K|       |   121   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  52 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL               | SYS_TEMP_0FDA4CB1D_E5C2B79E |  5692 |  1206K|       |   121   (1)| 00:00:01 |
```

Comment: You've given us no information to go on. I could ask you "I've got a query but it's slow. Why?" Could you answer my question? Do you see that you've asked a very similar question - i.e. one without any information that might allow us to help you diagnose the problem? Please update your question to include the view and queries in question, along with execution plans for both the good and bad queries (see https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-create-an-execution-plan if you are unsure how to do that). We might then be able to help you. Bonus points for a complete test case demonstrating the issue!

Comment: We can't see your view definition, tables, indexes, data or the statements you are running, or their execution plans. So this is very vague and abstract.

Comment: In generally I want to know why there is a difference between view and with, but ok - I added the whole code.

Answer (score 3):

> "In generally I want to know why there is a difference between view and with"

In tuning there are very universally applicable rules. Mostly things depend on the specifics. So it your case the pertinent point is this step in the second Explain Plan:

```
TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION
```

Basically, tuning a query which joins tables and views is hard, because the optimizer can't really be sure how many rows the view will return. This often results in a bad plan, as it does here. If you look at the first plan, the optimizer has opted for `VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE`. This means it will query your view once for every row in the other tables. Twice, because of the MINUS operator. Because the optimizer is pushing predicates into the view query (`ENG_OWNER.MIS_TAMH, ENG_OWNER.COMPANY`) it is using a series of Nested Loops to execute the view's query. For large tables this can be an expensive operation.

Whereas, with the WITH clause the optimizer can see all the tables in the one query and can take the decision to materialize the subquery result set as a temporary table. Temporary tables aren't always performative, because they involve writing to and reading from a temporary tablespace, and many DBAs don't bother to configure their tablespaces appropriately. However, the big advantage of materialization is that the view query is executed just once, and (provided the result set is small enough) read once and maintained in memory.

As materialization seems to work you could using the hint. Instead of a WITH clause that has the whole query from the view just do

```
with CC_MC_VIEW  as (select /*+ materialize  */ 
                     from dwh.CC_MC_VIEW )
select ...
```

Comment: OK thanks. I'm not sure what is your mean when you say "That means the database is constantly re-querying your whole view's result set for every row in the other tables"...
So, you think that the solution is realy to remove the view from query and replace it with the with clause?

Comment: Rewritten my answer to be a bit clearer as to what (I think) is happening. Including the access information (from the bottom of the Explain Plans) would make it easier to be certain about the CBO's decision making.

Answer (score 1):

Generally on Oracle there should be no difference. With clause can be either INLINEed or MATERIALIZEd. Look at documentation how to use these hints. Also the way how a VIEW can be "embedded" into execution plan can be modified. Look at docs and search parameters complex_view_merging/simple_view_merging.

The best you can do is to compare execution plans for both. Without seeing them nobody can help you. Theoretically Oracle optimizer should generate identical exec plan for both cases if they are supposed to return identical results.

UPDATE: IN 2nd case the view is MATERIALIZED(see TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION). Oracle stored content on the VIEW query into TEMP tablespace and used it for further joining. Theoretically this should be slower than inlining(1st case).

as noted by @William INLINE/MATERIALIZE hint are officially undocumented.
unfortunately other parameters are also undocumented. 
Try to execute the slow query using sqlplus (not SqlDeveloper) 4x and change CBO parameters by setting (all 4 combinations/true/false)

```
alter session set "_complex_view_merging"=true;
alter session set "_simple_view_merging"=true;
```

And see what happens. And it might worth of trying remove the FULL hint from VIEW definition. You never know how yo will use the view, which predicates will be used and therefore the "FULL TABLE SCAN" on the table DWH_COMPANIES might not be necessary.

Comment: The `inline` and `materialize` hints are famously undocumented.

Comment: As I can understand, those hints used for cases you want to optimize the with clause. In my case, it's the opposite. The query with the "with" run great, the problem is with the one of view.